# MySQL 8 DISTINCT with greatest ID

Tags: mysql, sql, groupwise-maximum

Hopefully this is an easy problem, and I'm just thinking about it wrong.

I have an association between `id_1` and `id_2`. There is a 1->n relationship between `id_1` and `id_2`. Namely, if no `id_2` exists for `id_1` it has a default value of -1. This can look like:

```
id_1   id_2   info
---- | ---- | ----
120   -1      'dont'
120   444     'show'
123   -1      'test'
124   -1      'hello'
125   -1      'world'
125   123     'oh wait'
126   -1      'help'
126   201     'me'
127   -1      'sql'
127   206     'hell'
```

Basically I want to have a SQL query that gets the highest `id_2` associated with an `id_1`, given an `IN` statement matching criteria from `id_1`. If I can't have an `IN` statement that's also fine as well, I'm just trying to optimize something else.

Here is what the answer should look like given `id_1` containing `(123,124,125,126,127)` and `id_2` containing `(-1,-1,123,201,206)`:

```
id_1   id_2   info
---- | ---- | ----
123    -1     'test'
124    -1     'hello'
125    123    'oh wait'
126    201    'me'
127    206    'hell'
```

Notice how `id_1` `120` ends up excluded. I've tried:

```
SELECT DISTINCT id_1, id_2, info
FROM ids
WHERE
      id_1 IN (123, 124, 125, 126, 127) AND
      id_2 IN (-1, -1, 123, 201, 206)
```

But this gives multiple `id_2` values for a single `id_1`.

I've also tried a `GROUP BY` on `id_2` but that only gives me one `id_1` that has -1.

```
SELECT id_1, id_2, info
FROM ids
WHERE
      id_1 IN (123, 124, 125, 126, 127) AND
      id_2 IN (-1, -1, 123, 201, 206)
GROUP BY id_2
```

results in:

```
id_1   id_2    info
----- | ---- | ----
123    -1     'test'
125    123    'oh wait'
126    201    'me'
127    206    'hell'
```

Note the missing `id_1` of `124`.

So how can I write this query to get the most recent, distinct `id_2` for an `id_1`?

Comment: Your GROUP BY is invalid and expected to raise an error. (And will do so in newer MySQL versions, unless in compatibility mode.)

Comment: Don't forget to _specify_ the expected result.

Comment: @jarlh strange, I must be in compatibility mode o_o, also updated the question to show the expected answer, where only `id_1` is included based on criteria.

Comment: This is probably a good use for `NULL` -- instead of "-1".  `MAX(id2)` gives the same answer either way.

Comment: Was "120" deliberately left out?  Why?  Is that exclusion part of the Question?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may user `ROW_NUMBER` if on MySQL 8+:

```sql
WITH cte AS (
    SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY id_1 ORDER BY id_2 DESC) rn
    FROM ids
    WHERE id_1 IN (123, 124, 125, 126, 127) AND
          id_2 IN (-1, -1, 123, 201, 206)
)

SELECT id_1, id_2, info
FROM cte
WHERE rn = 1;
```

On earlier versions of MySQL, you can identify the max record per `id_1` group using exists logic:

```sql
SELECT i1.*
FROM ids i1
WHERE id_1 IN (123, 124, 125, 126, 127) AND
      id_2 IN (-1, -1, 123, 201, 206) AND
      NOT EXISTS (
          SELECT 1
          FROM ids i2
          WHERE i2.id_1 = i1.id_1 AND
                i2.id_2 > i1.id_2 AND
                i2.id_1 IN (123, 124, 125, 126, 127) AND
                i2.id_2 IN (-1, -1, 123, 201, 206)
      );
```

Comment: How can you add pre-defined `id_1` / `id_2` into this?

Comment: I don't understand your comment, but I sense that perhaps you are making your problem more complicated than it has to be.

Comment: I also want to exclude certain id_1's. I'll update my original question, apologies.

Comment: @Alex Based on your latest update, I think you just need to add restrictions in the `WHERE` clause limiting to certain `id_1` and `id_2` values.